# How do I provide the connection string file for ORDS on Kubernetes?

Tags: openshift

I am using the [oracle database operator](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-database-operator) to manage lifecycle of PDBs in a multitenant model. I've followed the specific steps for the [multitenant model](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-database-operator/blob/main/docs/multitenant/README.md).
While applying the [CDB CRD yaml file](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-database-operator/blob/main/docs/multitenant/provisioning/cdb.yaml) (I've edited the values accordingly), the new pod that is provisioned gives an error saying that it cannot find the "conn_string.txt" file.

```
INFO : This container will start a service running ORDS 22.4.4 and APEX 22.2.0.

ERROR: CONN_STRING_FILE has not added, create a file with CONN_STRING variable and added as docker volume:

mkdir volume ; echo 'CONN_STRING=user/password@hostname:port/service_name' > volume/conn_string.txt
```

I was able to successfully run a separate ORDS image as a deployment([yaml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javiermugueta/ordscontainer/master/ordscontainer.yaml)) where I attached the "conn_string.txt" file as a configMap. So I am sure my "conn_string.txt" file has the right format and details. (The yaml file provided is the example I linked. I edited it to add the volume and volumeMount to attach the configMap).

I did not see any documentation about this error on the oracle operator github page linked above. How do I resolve this issue? Are there any ways to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Trying for hours here is how i got it running:

1. Create a ConfigMap that looks something like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  conn_string.txt: >-
    CONN_STRING=sys/password@hostname:1521/XEPDB1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ords-conn-string
  namespace: storage
```

2. When creating your Deployment/Pod make sure to mount your ConfigMap to `/opt/oracle/variables/` (don't forget the tailing / !!!).

With the important bits looking like this:

```yaml
 volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/oracle/variables/
              name: vol-fijxn
```

```yaml
 volumes:
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: ords-conn-string
            optional: false
          name: vol-fijxn
```

My slightly trimmed Manifest looked something like this:

```yaml
spec:
      containers:
        - image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/ords:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: ords
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8181
              name: ords
              protocol: TCP
              _serviceType: ClusterIP
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
            runAsNonRoot: false
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/oracle/variables/
              name: vol-fijxn
          _init: false
          __active: true
          resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: oracle-registry
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: ords-conn-string
            optional: false
          name: vol-fijxn
```

Hope this helps!